# How to response a custom uppercase header in NestJS?

Tags: nestjs

I want to output a response with all uppercase letter. But NestJS would automatically convert the header to lower case.

```js
@Get()
async test(@Response() res: Res) {
  res.setHeader('X-CUSTOM-HEADER', 'FOOBAR'); // res.header and res.set also output the same result
  res.send();
}
```

This output `X-Custom-Header: FOOBAR` in the header but not `X-CUSTOM-HEADER: FOOBAR`.

Comment: HTTP headers are case insensitive. [It's explained here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is not the problem of NestJS.
`res.setHeader()` can set and response a uppercase header.

The problem is I was using Cloudflare on my server and it rewritten my header to lower case.

I have to rewrite the header in Cloudflare and this is what I did.
https://developers.cloudflare.com/terraform/additional-configurations/transform-rules/

```
resource "cloudflare_ruleset" "response-header" {
  zone_id     = "<ZONE_ID>"
  name        = "response-header"
  description = "response header"
  kind        = "zone"
  phase       = "http_response_headers_transform"
  rules {
    action  = "rewrite"
    action_parameters {
      headers {
        name       = "X-CUSTOM-HEADER"
        operation  = "set"
        expression = "http.response.headers[\"x-custom-header\"][0]"
      }
    }
    expression  = "true"
    description = "Transform response header"
  }
}
```